# Can "eine Ablehnung erteilen" be used to voice an opinion or does it imply decision power?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I read this in a newspaper article discussing some possible measures for a Corona virus lockdown. The journalist wanted to say that a particular interest group is against a specific measure and used the expression *"eine Ablehnung erteilen"*.

This struck me as an odd phrase because this group can express their opinion but they don't actually get to make any of the relevant decisions. Is this a proper use of this expression?

Comment: Could you cite the phrase from the article please?

Comment: @calculatormathematical it was on die Zeit but I didn't find it anymore. It was posted 2 days ago and articles change quickly.

Answer (score 3):

The used phrase seems to be have been patched together on the fly. While *eine Abfuhr erteilen* is frequently used, the combination *Ablehnung erteilen* sound strange. *Erteilen* frequently suggests an official statement, which does not seem appropriate for a  disagreement (no matter, how intense).

I agree, that an interest group can only voice its opinion and desires, but hardly issue an official decision.

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ablehnung) (see section "Typische Verbindungen") lists *auf Ablehnung stoßen* as one of the most frequent combinations.

Considering comments:
I guess, that in the given examples it is simply sloppy phrasing (as opposed to an established technical phrase): a **person** has to accept (*Zustimmung erteilen*), while a **proposal** would be rejected (*auf Abstimmung stoßen*). This would require more complicated phrasing, so I consider the examples (acceptance or rejection of browser cookies, acceptance or rejection of vaccination) as preference of a slightly ugly use of verb (so it can be shared) to cleaner phrasing.

(*Abfuhr erteilen* would share the verb more easily, but has a somewhat rough connotation.)

Of course, plenty of alternatives exist, like

> Zustimmung erteilen oder verweigern or even simpler: zustimmen oder ablehnen

Comment: I guess it rather should have been *eine Absage erteilen* but it's hard to tell without context.

Comment: "Ablehnung erteilen" sounds in fact strange, but it is used as a Google search shows, See [here](https://www.sah-leipzig.de/impfung/) and [here](https://www.roleff-shop.de/Sitemap). It seems to be a technical term: "Sie können jederzeit den verschiedenen Cookie-Kategorien Ihre Zustimmung oder Ablehnung erteilen oder nur ganz gezielt bestimmte Cookies zulassen."

Answer (score 0):

First lets look at the word *"Ablehnung"*

> [**Ablehnung**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/ablehnung)
>
> feminine noun
>
> 1. (= Zurückweisung) refusal; (von Antrag, Bewerber etc) rejection
>    auf Ablehnung stoßen to be refused/rejected, to meet with a refusal/a rejection
> 2. (= Missbilligung) disapproval
>    auf Ablehnung stoßen to meet with disapproval

This answers half the question, even if the said group has no vote in the matter they are able to publicly reject a given proposal or measure. In other words to take a stance, let their position be known, issue a statement that in case was public (and caries with it the groups weight).

The other word,

> [**Erteilen**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/erteilen)
>
> transitive verb
>
> to give; Genehmigung auch to grant; Auftrag auch to place (jdm with sb); Lizenz to issue jdm einen Verweis erteilen to reproach sb

Simply means in this case, "to impart", "to make known", "to give them knowledge off".

Comment: For me, the conclusion is missing. You described what both words mean, but can they go together? Would the combination be understood, idiomatic, odd?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich absolutely yes, so obvious it goes without saying. But if you want to take the time and effort and write your own answer - be my guest.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that in the case you have described, the author confounded the phrase "eine Abfuhr erteilen" (to reject) with "eine Ablehnung erteilen" (to issue a formal rejection). The latter phrase is only used when a legal entity (a person, company, or institution) makes use of their legal right to reject a legally effective call for action, e.g. a private health insurance company rejects the application of an applicant:

> Eine private Krankenversicherung erteilt einem Anwärter eine Ablehnung auf seinen Antrag.